# emulate std::async with std::launch::sync?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, future

I would like to implement a method like this:

```
boost::unique_future<int> foo()
{
    return defer([=] // call this lambda on boost::unique_future<int>::get();
    {
         return prime(10);
    });
}
```

I know of `boost::promise` and `boost::packaged_task` and `set_wait_callback`, however since the returned future takes a reference to either this will not work?

I know there is `std::async` and `std::launch::sync`, but how can emulate it using boost and vs2010?

```
std::unique_future<int> foo()
{
    return std::async(std::launch::sync, [=] 
    {
         return prime(10);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** use `set_wait_callback`, you just have to dynamically allocate the promise, and delete it in the callback after you set the value:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void callback(boost::promise<int>&p) {
    std::cout<<"callback"<<std::endl;
    p.set_value(42);
    delete &p;
}

boost::unique_future<int> f()
{
    boost::promise<int> *p=new boost::promise<int>;
    p->set_wait_callback(callback);
    return p->get_future();
}

int main()
{
    boost::unique_future<int> uf(f());
    std::cout<<"main()"<<std::endl;
    int val=uf.get();
    std::cout<<"val="<<val<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: One mayor problem. If get() is not called then the promise is leaked.

Comment: If you use a shared_ptr<promise> then you will get a circular dependency and it will still leak.

Comment: You're right. The best solution would be to modify the boost code to do what you want.

Comment: I solved it with `boost::detail::future_object` and a `reintepret_cast` trick to create a `boost::unique_future`. Very ugly, but it works without modifying boost.

Comment: Could you explain your solution with a bit more detail? I think I ran into a similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066667/pattern-for-future-conversion and I'd really like to see how you managed to call the hidden c'tor of boost::unique_future to store your own future_object there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ticket's code : https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4710

Comment: Though that will just execute the task right away on the other thread, I only want it to execute on `get`.